# JSFiddle - get jquery plugin example working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jsfiddle

Im having a bad morning and can't seem to get the example code from the plugin (http://workshop.rs/2009/12/jqbargraph-jquery-graph-plugin/) working in JSFiddle.  Can anyone see what I am missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/k86u5gsp/8/

```
<div id="chart"></div> 

arrayOfData = new Array(
[[14,54,26],'2007'],
[[8,48,38],'2008'],
[[4,36,57],'2009']
);  


$('#chart').jqBarGraph({ data: arrayOfData });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing 2 things.

```
1. https://jqbargraph.googlecode.com/files/jqBarGraph.1.1.js

2. colors: ['#242424','#437346','#97D95C']
```

check out this http://jsfiddle.net/rxm4ymLs/

is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I added http://workshop.rs/jqbargraph/jqBarGraph.js via the external link instead. Not sure why that didn't work but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you're missing to include js script file in your jsfiddle example :D
Try to add `<script src="https://jqbargraph.googlecode.com/files/jqBarGraph.1.1.min.js"></script>` before `<div id="chart"></div>`